# Python3 requests not properly encoding spaces

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, python-3.8

This should be pretty simple, but its simplicity is making it hard for me to google properly.

```
url = "https://www.example.com/api/card/list/?q=" + name
r = requests.get(url)
```

if name = "Test", it works fine. If I set name = "Test with space", the spaces arent passed through properly.

If I manually navigate to {url}?q=Test+with+space I get the results I expect, but when I let the python script execute, I do not get the expected result.

Edit:

Made some changes but still doesnt seem to work

```
payload = {'q': name}
params = urllib.parse.urlencode(payload, quote_via=urllib.parse.quote)
url = "https://www.example.com/api/card/list/"
r = requests.get(url, params=params)
```

Edit 2:

I figured out more issue. I piped the request through an HTTP proxy. The request to example.com goes to Cloudflare, which is encoding the Name and causing the issue.

In the end, the issue was Cloudflare was redirecting all www. traffic to @. and re-encoding the string again.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudflare redirect caused double encoding